# Expression language protoyping in xpages app

Tags: xpages, el

In an app I am serving multiple languages via strings properties files.

In a menu the reference in link may look as followed:

```
<xp:link
    text="#{strings.menu_label_mandate_request}"
    title="#{strings.menu_label_mandate_request}"
    value="/mandate.xsp" styleClass="plainLink">
</xp:link>
```

This is working fine.

Now I want to define the links in a java class and loop through it via a repeat control but keeping in tact the multi-language support.

In my Menu class I create an array of Page objects and set the properties as followed:

```
this.navigation = new ArrayList<Page>();
        this.navigation.add(new Page("menu_label_mandate_request", "mandate.xsp", "fa fa-users", false));
...
```

I have added a repeat control on an xsp to initiate the class (via a managed bean):

```
<xp:repeat id="rptNavigation" rows="30"disableOutputTag="true" value="#{javascript:menu.navigation}" var="nav">
```

However I have problems setting the correct prototyping (if possible):

```
<xp:link
    text="#{strings.nav.label}"
    title="#{strings.nav.label}"
    value="/mandate.xsp" styleClass="plainLink">
</xp:link>
```

So i get the error message:
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key nav
Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key nav

Does anyone have an idea what I have overlooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expressing what the dynamic value `nav` should be as a literal object and not as a reference. Write:

```
<xp:link
    text="#{strings[nav.label]}"
    title="#{strings[nav.label]}"
    value="/mandate.xsp" styleClass="plainLink">
</xp:link>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I was almost going back to SSJS: eval("strings['" + nav.getLabel()+ "']")